# How to make sure METIS partition surface mesh connected?

Tags: mesh, cgal, surface, terrain, metis

I'm a new learner in CGAL and Metis, I'm trying to partition a surface mesh with CGAL and METIS. However, when I used example code from CGAL[here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/BGL_surface_mesh_2surface_mesh_partition_8cpp-example.html), it could cause seperate meshes. I only want the connected mesh to be partitioned together. Is there any parameters I can adjust to fix this problem? Thank you so much for your help :D! [Seperate clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQOG9.png)

P.S. Whether there are ways that only the triangles share the most boundaries will be clustered together?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Metis for that. You can use the function [`PMP::connected_components()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__keep__connected__components__grp.html#ga4b265482ec76e147764f0ca64a90b55d) like in [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2face_filtered_graph_example_8cpp-example.html#a5) (you can call `CGAL::copy_face_graph(ffg, my_mesh)`) to extract a copy of a connected component.

Comment: Hiii, thank you so much for your explanation, sry I didn't clarify it, the original mesh is connected, so I need to partition the mesh with METIS. However, the result mesh clusters could have parts that are not connected (like in the pic), I only want the clusters to be connected.  And yes I can use this function to process the partition result in the following steps, but whether I can do it directly with METIS? Thank you so much for your time ^V^!

Comment: Ahhh I found an example in https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/BGL_polyhedron_3_2polyhedron_partition_8cpp-example.html ^V^ Sry I didn't notice that! Thank you so much for your help!